# iTunes now takes up 100% of CPU since updating to 11.3

Tags: itunes, macbook-pro, macos, cpu

#### UPDATE:

The issue seems to be at least related to what **konqui** mentioned in the Comments since I do have a large library of podcasts. However, if this was merely related to re-indexing then one would expect things to go back to normal but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Basically, now everything (related to podcasts, at least) takes about **100** times longer than it *should* take. For instance, after clicking on the podcasts tab itself, it takes 10 seconds (with CPU at 100%) and just *refreshing* podcasts has taken up to 30 minutes.

---

Since updating iTunes to **Version 11.3**, it quickly takes up 100% of the CPU and stops responding every time I try to open it.
I've tried:

- Waiting for it to sort itself out on its own
- Force Quitting (and then re-starting iTunes)
- Re-starting my computer entirely (MBP, running **Version 10.9.4**) and then trying both previous approaches.

Has anyone heard of this issue before? Should I uninstall 11.3? And, if so, how do I do this?

Again, this problem has only started happening since updating to Version 11.3 two days ago.

Another strange thing is that iTunes does not appear to be totally frozen--for a few seconds the "(not responding)" will occasionally disappear and then reappear. Plus, in those few seconds that it starts to respond again, its status will change (for instance, now it says it is "Processing Album Artwork" and earlier a random podcast started playing). However, this doesn't seem to explain why the **% CPU** consistently remains at around 100%. [**UPDATE**: The 100% CPU/"Not Responding"-status may, for some reason, be related to podcasts being refreshed]

Currently, the only Applications I have open are:

- Activity Monitor
- Google Chrome
- iTunes
- Finder

Comment: if it is podcasting you should see that in high network usage in activity monitor

Comment: Do you have a large File Collection? if so it may take it's time. As far as i know iTunes reindexes/validates the whole Library each first newstart after an update. I would recommend you to let it run over night and have a look at the next day if it still hangs. If so open Console and take a look into the iTunes log file and maybe the system log.

Comment: @Buscar웃: What I meant was this: after about 30 minutes the CPU load dropped down to normal levels, which made me think the problem had sorted itself out. Then, the first thing I did was click to refresh podcasts and the same issue started happening again. (That's why I thought it was somehow connected to refreshing podcasts).

Comment: @konqui: I sort of did try running it overnight--I fell asleep while the issue was going on and in the morning the computer was asleep and, when woken up, it still had the same issue.

Comment: @konqui: The problem, however, is that I really have no idea what to look for in the Console log--any suggestions? Also, as mentioned in my update, now iTunes is at least *operable* but with very long lags, especially when the podcasts automatically refresh. Other than making this less frequent (currently it occurs hourly), I'm not sure what to do to at least *minimize* the extended lags...

Comment: to start with i would have a look for the words error, fail, hang, wait and retry in the iTunes log file. Around the Time the Problem starts. If you never had looked into a log file before it may be a little hard to find what you are looking for. if you think you won't be able to find what you are looking for then just post the log file so we can have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since upgrading to iTunes 11.3 I have experienced a very similar problem.  Every time I refresh my podcasts, iTunes' memory/CPU usage surges, and the iTunes UI freezes up for 5-10 minutes.

I haven't found a complete solution, but I have stumbled across a temporary workaround.  On my system, the problem only seems to occur when I refresh podcasts while looking at them in the `List` view, as in the screenshot below:

[image: List View]

If instead I refresh podcasts from the `All Unplayed` view, there is no freezing at all:

[image: All Unplayed View]

It appears that the issue is related to viewing the podcast list while refreshing all podcasts.  (You can even avoid the issue if you click refresh in `List` view and then quickly click away to another view, like `Music.`)

Not a super satisfying answer, I know, but for me it has returned iTunes to a semi-usable state.

Comment: I had a feeling the podcasts were connected to the problem but it never would've occurred to me that it was the list view specifically. This may not be a complete solution but it's a *whole lot* better than it was before.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try to restart your computer. Sometimes, it works for me when my computer runs pretty slow. You don't know what you've run on your computer.